# Create new local branch with latest changes from upstream

Tags: git, branch

I am wondering how to create a new branch and automatically grab the latest changes from upstream using one command?

Because right now it is a two commands action, I am sure there should be a way...

Thanks

Comment: Which "two commands" are you already using? You could probably put them together into a single git alias, which would give you the effect that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create a new branch when pulling from a remote repository, you could do:

`git pull repoName remoteBranch:newLocalBranch`

**ex:** `git pull origin master:newBranch`

Or, if you have already fetched and are looking to create a new branch at a specific commit:

`git checkout -b newBranch commitToCheckout`

**ex:**  `git checkout -b newBranch 0123456`, where `0123456` is the commit hash.